# How to connect to remote Hadoop/Hive table through Talend?

Tags: hadoop, talend

I have access to a remote hadoop environment through a url (http://host:port), username and password protected.

I want to be be able to connect to the environment and load data from a local csv into a Hive or Impala table.

Is it possible to connect to a remote Hadoop environment and do this without any Hadoop connectors configured through Talend ????

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create connetion somewhere - it can be in tJDBCconnection component or in Metadata>DB Connections sections

Comment: If I was to use the tjdbcconnection component how would i know the Driver JAR or the Driver Class?

Comment: Talend will tell you what driver jar is missing - you can install them on your own. Driver Class I have from my admin, so you should ask your admin for all necessery info.